# Jooq-codegen downgrade after set explicit version

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jooq

I got a problem with **jooq-codegen** version.

In main `build.gradle` I got spring boot in `2.4.5` version and in dependency part:

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq')
```

I also use dependencyMangement:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

and in child project `build.gradle` in dependency part I add version '3.14.8'

```
compile("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.14.8")
```

But after I run command:

```
 gw -q dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath | grep jooq
```

I got this:

```
|    |    |    |    +--- org.jooq:jooq:3.14.8 -> 3.13.5
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq -> 2.4.5
|    |    |    \--- org.jooq:jooq:3.14.8 -> 3.13.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.14.8 -> 3.13.5
|    |    |    +--- org.jooq:jooq:3.13.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.13.5
|    |    |         \--- org.jooq:jooq:3.13.5 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq -> 2.4.5 (*).   
|    +--- org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.14.8 -> 3.13.5 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq -> 2.4.5 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq -> 2.4.5 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq -> 2.4.5 (*)
```

How can I fix this downgrade? And why is it happen?

Comment: have you tried to also make your `org.jooq:jooq:3.14.8` dependency explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it in main `build.gradle` file adding:

```
jooq {
  version = dependencyManagement.importedProperties['jooq.version']
}
```

and remove all explicit version from Gradle files